# Type cast getActivity in Fragment giving inconvertible types

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Launch Activity: Mainactivity,
FragmentLaunch Activity: FragHandler (With View Pager and tabs),
Fragment Activity: Frag1

```
Error: FragHanlder can not be cast to Mainactivity
```

Using Code as per guidance:

```
 new ColorChooserDialog.Builder((MainActivity)getActivity(),R.string.color_palette)
                    .titleSub(R.string.colors)
                    .preselect(startuppri)
                    .show();
```

Below are classed imported in Fragment.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager;
```

Comment: I was trying earlier with new ColorChooserDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.string.color_palette)
                            .titleSub(R.string.colors)
                            .preselect(startuppri)
                            .show();

Comment: For the sake of completeness, getActivity is a method call, just use it that way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Is this the issue you are getting?

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/683

Comment: yes, same issue. I was trying to get it. Thanks for picking and putting here.

Comment: but solution is not working. I m getting error Frag1 cannot be cast to Mainactivity

Comment: Which `Activity` contains your `Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to type cast with you parent activity and not with your fragment

```
new ColorChooserDialog.Builder((YourActivity)getActivity, R.string.color_palette)
                        .titleSub(R.string.colors)
                        .preselect(startuppri)
                        .show();
```

Comment: So, if I have Mainactivity which is called on app loading. FragHandler Activity with viewpager to handle Fragments under tab. Then I have to used Mainactivity for type cast, right?

Comment: Using your input, error goes off while compiling but when I call method, It again gives same error of FragHandler can not cast to Mainactivity.

Comment: This is constructor for builder class.  public <ActivityType extends AppCompatActivity & ColorCallback> Builder(@NonNull ActivityType context, @StringRes int title) {
            mContext = context;
            mTitle = title;
        }

Comment: why you are parsing , try to send direct getAcvitity()